# Solve $\begin{cases} (x+y)^2+3(x-y)=30 \\ xy+3(x-y)=11 \end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\begin{cases} (x+y)^2+3(x-y)=30 \\ xy+3(x-y)=11 \end{cases}$

I subtracted the bottom equation from the top:

$\Rightarrow (x+y)^2-xy=19$

And then I'm stuck because I can't come up with a new equation from these three.

Comment: Instead try subtracting four times the second from the first.

Comment: Hint: Let $x - y = a, xy = b$.  (This also explains Macavity's comment)

Comment: Thanks... so how in the world can you tell immediately to multiply the second by $4$? I mean is this some technique or natural math intuition if you don't mind telling me. Because there's no way I see this.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson One way to approach it, is that if we want to make $x-y$ the only unknown, then $(x+y)^2 - 4xy = (x-y)^2$, with is why we "multiply the second by 4".  My phrasing of $a, b$ makes that thought process much more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{gathered}
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  {\left( {x + y} \right)^2} + 3\left( {x - y} \right) = 30 \hfill \\
  xy + 3\left( {x - y} \right) = 11 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  {\left( {x - y} \right)^2} + 4xy + 3\left( {x - y} \right) = 30 \hfill \\
  xy = 11 - 3\left( {x - y} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
   \Leftrightarrow {\left( {x - y} \right)^2} + 4\left( {11 - 3\left( {x - y} \right)} \right) + 3\left( {x - y} \right) = 30 \hfill \\
   \Leftrightarrow {\left( {x - y} \right)^2} - 9\left( {x - y} \right) + 14 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{gathered}
  x - y = 2 \hfill \\
  x - y = 7 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
   * \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x - y = 2 \hfill \\
  xy = 5 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \Leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{gathered}
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = 1 - \sqrt 6  \hfill \\
  y =  - 1 - \sqrt 6  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = 1 + \sqrt 6  \hfill \\
  y =  - 1 + \sqrt 6  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
   * \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x - y = 7 \hfill \\
  xy =  - 10 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \Leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{gathered}
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = 2 \hfill \\
  y =  - 5 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = 5 \hfill \\
  y =  - 2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$